# Java sorting with Comparator and Inner classes

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, inner-classes

Given this combination of Java classes:

```
public class OuterClass
    {
        public String           field01;
        public int              field02;
        public InnerClass       innerField
        // ...getters, setters

    public class InnerClass
        {
            public int              innerField01;
            public BigDecimal       innerField02;
            // ...getters, setters
```

I want to order them by outer and inner fields. Now, given a `List<OuterClass> list`, I can easily sort that by e.g., `field01` with:

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(OuterClass::getField01));
```

But which way may I sort by `InnerClass.innerfield.innerfield01`? I tried

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(OuterClass::InnerField::innerField01));
```

and few other ways, but with no success.
Maybe I should use in some way `OuterClass::new`, but I don't know how.

Comment: Please note that one solution I found is to provide some getters to get innerclass fields from the outer class, but I would like to avoid this solution, which is not general and leads to writing as many getters as the number of inner fields.

Comment: You need to tell the comparator which fields you are going to compare, so you must have those fields accessible to your comparator, by getters. Another way is to implement ```Comparable```.

Comment: BTW: Are you aware of the differences between [inner classes and static nested classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)? Because your usage of inner classes as a field of its enclosing class looks suspicious here (but maybe it's the desired behavior).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [Comparator.comparing(Function, Comparator)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-) like this:

```
Collections.sort(list, 
  Comparator.comparing(OuterClass::getInnerField, 
    Comparator.comparingInt(InnerClass::getInnerField01)));
```

The first argument is the function used to extract the key on which you want to sort. In your case: the `Innerfield` from the `OuterClass`.

The second argument is the Comparator used to compare the sort key. In your case: a `Comparator` for one of the fields of the `InnerField` (`innerField01` in the example above).

Answer (score 1):

Let both outer and inner class implement `Comparable` and add a `compareTo` method to both or just let outer class implement it and handle all comparison there. Which way is best depends on how you want to compare, in the below example Outer is sorted first, then Inner

```
public class OuterClass implements Comparable{
    public String           field01;
    public int              field02;
    public InnerClass       innerField;

    public class InnerClass implements Comparable {
        public int              innerField01;
        public BigDecimal       innerField02;

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object o) {
            //...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        OuterClass obj = (OuterClass)o;
        int res = field01.compareTo(obj.field01);

        if (res != 0) {
            return res;
        }
        return this.innerField.compareTo(obj.innerField);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to accept also this solution. Actually in my case I would need just one compare on the outer class since it can access to the field of the inner class, and make a rule for each field I need to compare.

Answer (score -1):

`Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(obj -> obj.getInnerField().getInnerField01()));`